# Qt how doing a blocking wait until receiving data

Tags: qt, wait

I have a qt program. I have CAN requests that I want to send in sequential order. 
I want to wait for answers, before sending other requests.

```
SendReadLatchCommand(fam,prod,addr,0x00000000, 4);  // 1st request

// wait for answer and analyze it??

SendReadLatchCommand(fam,prod,addr,0x00000002, 4);  // 2nd request
```

I have a receiveData() method, called by my thread of reception, where I save the received message.

I want to sleep in my main program and we awake when receiving answer.

I can't use signal/slot because in the slot, I don't know what is the last request I sent, so I can't continue emitting requests.

How can I do this?
thanks

Comment: waitForReadData(), but really try to extract it to the slot, one way is with QStateMachines (if a bit overkill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is a good idea to block your main thread, however it can be done by using a binary semaphore, which is the same as a counting semaphore with a maxCount of 1. Therefore one can use a counting semaphore [QSemaphore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsemaphore.html)

Typically, a QSemaphore is implemented in terms of QWaitCondition (refer Qt help). One could block on a wait condition until the CAN thread signals the wait condition. One can hide the blocking on the wait behind some interface e.g:

```
//--- Very simple implementation - concept only

QWaitCondition cond_;
QMutex mutex_;

void rxThreadHandler( /*args*/ )
{
  while( !quitCalled() )
  {
    waitOnReceivedData();//Blocks, I assume...
    handleReceivedData();
    answerRxd(); 
  }
}

void answerRxd()
{
  QMutexLocker lock( mutex_ );
  cond_.wakeAll();
}

void sendNext( const Buffer& buffer )
{
  QMutexLocker guard( mutex_ );
  //Waits/Blocks until condition signalled, then locks mutex 
  // to prevent further signalling (might block rx thread)
  cond_.wait( lock.mutex() );
  //Unlocking mutex explicitly to allow receipt of data
  guard.unlock();
  //Now send as result of previous receive. This does not
  // prevent receiving thread...     
  sendNextImpl( const Buffer& buffer );
}
```

Comment: While QSemaphore is notable, I consider QEventLoop a better construct for the purpose. QSemaphore may be extended to create a producer/consumer architecture, where the waiting thread becomes the consumer. I've implemented an architecture like this that produces callbacks that are executed by the consumer, but the code is extensive.

Comment: In retrospect, I think a normal conditional wait behind the correct interface is sufficient for this purpose. An EventLoop might be an overkill, but I can't yet see why it cannot be a solution.

Comment: I like your solution, but I tried QWaitCondition and it blocks my reception thread, as it receives a lot of other messages, it seems impossible to block the thread. So, I will implement a sort of sequencer. I save the last message sent, and analyze answers at reception.

Comment: Sorry for only answering now. I'm not sure whether the sending to the can device is blocking or non-blocking. If blocking, it means the mutex is locked unnecessarily long, preventing the receiving thread from receiving. I've modify my solution slightly.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you properly, you wanted to process the request *synchronously*.

Look into the `QEventLoop` in the qtdoc, you can do it this way:

```
QEventLoop wait_loop;
// 1st request
connect(request_1, SIGNAL(sig_answer_arrived()), &wait_loop, SLOT(quit()));
request_1->send_request();
wait_loop.exec();
// here we already got the answer
analyze_answer();

// the 2nd request does the same
```

Comment: I don't know QEventLoop, but I think it doest not the job. my requests ans answers are synchronous. I want to download a file on a distant bord. so I have to read addresses, send blocks. After each request, I wait for answer, I analyze it, if it is corrupted, I send it again. So I wanted a way to make my main thread wait for answer. Because, if I receive an answer in a different method, it is difficult to know the last request sent..  But I will try to save last state as a state machine and extract data analyze into  a slot..